# Macro Instruction - cannot select Record Details for Instruction Region

Tags: page-layout, macros

In the Macro Builder why can't I select the Record Detail component as a Region to add Instructions and update fields?
I have configured the Page Layout as a Feed Layout.
I can select fields from the Case Details

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Macros](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.macros_create_lightning.htm&type=5) work on the quick actions on the page layout so it's limited in what you can do vs. what you can see on a given page when it comes to record details. They're not able to do what you're proposing, but there is this idea asking to [Allow Macros to Edit Records/Fields Directly](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CZpZQAW). The builder only highlights what you're able to instruct on.

It's able to interact with your "Case Details" as it's a related record component that has a related update quick action (that you can see in lightning app builder).

Going off that, you can get what you're asking (update a field on current record), but the solution involves adding a quick action just for the macro's sake. If you create a quick action on that object (`action type = Update Record`) and then add it to the layout, you can then instruct your macro to fill it out and submit it, thus giving you an automated update of your desired field(s) on a given record.